# Protractor test failing in firefox (unable to find id) but works in ie/chrome

Tags: angularjs, firefox, protractor

I have a Protractor test that is running successfully against both IE and chrome, but when i run it against firefox an error is returned claiming that it can not find the element on the page - any ideas?

The HTML looks as follows - once the customer types letters into the box it attempts to provide options:

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-show="getCurrentTab()===1" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" data-ng-controller="RouteTabController">
<div class="form-group">
<b>FROM</b>
<div ba-auto-complete field="from" class="autoCompleteDirective" id="fromRoute"/>
</form>
```

The relevant code in the test is as follows:

```
var actions = browser.actions();
actions.mouseMove(element(by.id('fromRoute')));
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys("ABC");
```

On a side note I am using that as when I tried the following it claimed the element did not have focus in both chrome and firefox:

```
element(by.id('fromRoute')).click();
element(by.id('fromRoute')).sendKeys('ABC');
```

Comment: is any of those directives replacing div it is in? `replace: true`? Did you tried the div without closing it this way but with regular end tag? chrome is good at guessing endtags if it can't find one

Comment: Sorry that's what happens when you try to strip out a lot of following code from your html - there is a </div> at the end. So the code actually looks like:    <form data-ng-submit="submit()" data-ng-show="getCurrentTab()===1" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" data-ng-controller="RouteTabController">
<div class="form-group">
<b>FROM</b>
<div ba-auto-complete field="from" class="autoCompleteDirective" id="fromRoute"/> </div>
</form>

Comment: And the answer was ensure you have the latest version of the chrome driver.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (I'm ashamed to admit) was that my chrome driver was out of date. When I updated that then firefox worked ok